# reorder, join and remove elements of an array php

Tags: php

so I have an array that looks like this (easier to see then the raw output)

```
0  | from:2  page   | to:1  split
1  | from:1  split  | to:3  page
2  | from:1  split  | to:4  page
3  | from:1  split  | to:5  page
4  | from:3  page   | to:0  join
5  | from:4  page   | to:0  join
6  | from:5  page   | to:0  join
7  | from:8  page   | to:0  join
8  | from:0  join   | to:12 page
9  | from:1  split  | to:8  page
10 | from:12 page   | to:10 end
11 | from:   start  | to:2  page
```

what I would like to do is to somehow parse through it and come up with the following:

```
0 | start
1 | page
2 | split 3, 4, 5, 8
3 | page
4 | end
```

so essentially I'm trying to organize this into a final array that follows the path from start to finish.

Rules of engagement:

Where there is a split: combine the "to page" into a sub array, and where there is a "to join", remove the reference. and where there is a "from join to page" just make the page. so final output should look something like this:

```
array(
    'start',
    'page',
    'split' => array (
      3, 4, 5, 8
    ),
    'page',
    'end'
)
```

UPDATE:

here is the raw format I'm working with

```
Array
(
    [operators] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [type] => join
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [type] => split
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [type] => page
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [type] => page
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [type] => page
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [type] => page
                )

            [8] => Array
                (
                    [type] => page
                )

            [9] => Array
                (
                    [type] => start
                )

            [10] => Array
                (
                    [type] => end
                )

            [12] => Array
                (
                    [type] => page

                )

        )

    [links] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [fromOperator] => 2
                    [toOperator] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [fromOperator] => 1
                    [toOperator] => 3

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [fromOperator] => 1
                    [toOperator] => 4
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [fromOperator] => 1
                    [toOperator] => 5
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [fromOperator] => 3
                    [toOperator] => 0
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [fromOperator] => 4
                    [toOperator] => 0
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [fromOperator] => 5 
                    [toOperator] => 0
                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [fromOperator] => 8
                    [toOperator] => 0
                )

            [8] => Array
                (
                    [fromOperator] => 0
                    [toOperator] => 12
                )

            [9] => Array
                (
                    [fromOperator] => 1  
                    [toOperator] => 8

                )

            [10] => Array
                (
                    [fromOperator] => 12
                    [toOperator] => 10
                )

            [11] => Array
                (
                    [fromOperator] => 9
                    [toOperator] => 2

                )

        )

)

``
```

Comment: You better add the raw output too... Your format of the array is kinda confusing.

Comment: And show your attempted code. We're not going to design or write it for you. You're expected to make an attempt first, and then we'll help you fix it.

Comment: @barmar, ive attempted several ways and wasnt able to get remotely close and i didnt want to cause further confusion. sounds like im causing confusion regardless :P

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to mix associative and indexed elements in the same array.

Comment: This is some kind of directed graph problem? Maybe you should search google for algorithms to work with directed graphs.

Comment: @CodeMascot i updated the example to show the raw array i have to work with.

Comment: Tell me how to turn this [Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1352263024e1b1bee34d5e72dd560f723e8e55d6) into what you want.  It cant be done using your instructions....    how do I know the first item is `start` when its `from page to split`  and how do I know the last one is `end` when its `from start to page` - it makes no sense.

Comment: This is the best I can do [Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d0e3cc74b52a9db40c15534257f12a277079404f)

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix if you look at the `operators` array, `9` is `start`. this gives you an i dea of where to begin building.  then if you look at the `links` array and look for the `fromOperator = 9` you also get the `toOperator = 2` which is the index in the `operator` array for the next node im trying to build. i have to look between the 2 arrays to figure out how to plot the path to the end, then throw in the splits and my head starts spinning. see this graphic of what im trying to show in an array: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/3908350/c686d771de6fe6d6880e3a72e457ce87

Comment: @TjTate - I knew something was wrong, after a nap I was able to properly solve it.  Enjoy.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix you seriously rock thanks!!!!

Comment: Sure, It was fun...  I get bored with the same AJAX this, REGEX that, SQLInjection, how do I encrypt this .... yada yada... all the time.  That happens after doing PHP about a decade....  I cant promise it will work in every situation...

Comment: PS. I like your Screenshot, I'm working on a WP plugin that will have a flow chart type automation system that is simular.  I haven't gotten to the flowchart part.  That's a personal project. I am also working on a WP LMS plugin,  A rabbitmq RPC API for our queuing system at work, and a few other things .... lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Boo Yahh!!**

I had to nap on it, but now I got that 4 sure.

```
<?php
$array = array (
    'operators' => 
    array (
        0 => 
        array (
            'type' => 'join'
        ),
        1 => 
        array (
            'type' => 'split'
        ),
        2 => 
        array (
            'type' => 'page'
        ),
        3 => 
        array (
            'type' => 'page'
        ),
        4 => 
        array (
            'type' => 'page'
        ),
        5 => 
        array (
            'type' => 'page'
        ),
        8 => 
        array (
            'type' => 'page'
        ),
        9 => 
        array (
            'type' => 'start'
        ),
        10 => 
        array (
            'type' => 'end'
        ),
        12 => 
        array (
            'type' => 'page'
        ),
    ),
    'links' => 
    array (
        0 => 
        array (
            'fromOperator' => 2,
            'toOperator' => 1
        ),
        1 => 
        array (
            'fromOperator' => 1,
            'toOperator' => 3
        ),
        2 => 
        array (
            'fromOperator' => 1,
            'toOperator' => 4
        ),
        3 => 
        array (
            'fromOperator' => 1,
            'toOperator' => 5
        ),
        4 => 
        array (
            'fromOperator' => 3,
            'toOperator' => 0
        ),
        5 => 
        array (
            'fromOperator' => 4,
            'toOperator' => 0
        ),
        6 => 
        array (
            'fromOperator' => 5,
            'toOperator' => 0
        ),
        7 => 
        array (
            'fromOperator' => 8,
            'toOperator' => 0
        ),
        8 => 
        array (
            'fromOperator' => 0,
            'toOperator' => 12
        ),
        9 => 
        array (
            'fromOperator' => 1,
            'toOperator' => 8
        ),
        10 => 
        array (
            'fromOperator' => 12,
            'toOperator' => 10
        ),
        11 => 
        array (
            'fromOperator' => 9,
            'toOperator' => 2
        )
    )
);
```

Code:

```
//Flatten to simplify  [$op_id => $array['operators'][n]['type']]
//array_combine and array_keys, just makes sure the keys match
//the original array, because we are missing a few keys (7,8 and 11)
//we have to do this or we lose those references.
$arr_op = array_combine(array_keys($array['operators']), array_column($array['operators'], 'type'));
//print_r($arr_op);

//get our instruction list - combine data to simplify.
//this saves us a bit of work doing the lookup and managing multiple arrays
$instructions = [];
foreach($array['links'] as $link){
    $instructions[]  = [
        'fromOperator'  => $link['fromOperator'],
        'fromOp'        => $arr_op[$link['fromOperator']], // we need them keys to match here
        'toOperator'    => $link['toOperator'],
        'toOp'          => $arr_op[$link['toOperator']] //and here
    ];
} 
//print_r($instructions);

$opp_id = array_search('start',$arr_op); //9 start
//print_r($opp_id);

$i=0;
$output = [];

//loop as long as we have some instructions to process
while(count($instructions)){
    //get the current key of the array
    $key = key($instructions);

    //is this our instruction?
    //we are forced to {potentially} loop the whole array to find it
    //we cannot use array search (even after flattening it out) because of the duplicates
    if($instructions[$key]['fromOperator'] == $opp_id){
        //get and remove the instruction - array reduction
        $instruction = array_splice($instructions, $key, 1)[0];
        //print_r($instruction);
        //print_r($instructions);

        //just for sanity checks.
        echo "{$i}  | from:{$instruction['fromOp']}  {$instruction['toOperator']}  | to:{$instruction['fromOperator']}  {$instruction['toOp']}\n";

        //if the last operation is end, use it as there is no fromOp = end
        $opperation = 'end' == $instruction['toOp'] ? 'end' : $instruction['fromOp'];

        //process instruction
        switch($opperation){
            case 'join': 
                //skip
            break;
            case 'split':  
                //split has to be done as a group
                $output['split']=array_column(array_filter($array['links'],function($ins)use($opp_id){return $ins['fromOperator']==$opp_id;}),'toOperator');

            break;
            default: //start, page, end
                 $output[] = $opperation;
                 //when we find the end, break the switch, break the while
                 if($opperation == 'end') break 2; 
            break;
        }//end switch

        //get the operation key for the next instruction as we consumed it, Yum!
        $opp_id = $instruction['toOperator'];
        ++$i;
    }//end if

    //move the array pointer forward, or reset on false (start over when we hit the end of the array)
    if(false === next($instructions)) reset($instructions);
}//end while

echo "\n";
print_r($output);
```

Output

```
0  | from:start  2  | to:9  page
1  | from:page  1  | to:2  split
2  | from:split  4  | to:1  page
//Some "magic" happens here and we warp to 0
3  | from:page  0  | to:4  join
4  | from:join  12  | to:0  page
5  | from:page  10  | to:12  end

Array
(
    [0] => start
    [1] => page
    [split] => Array
    (
         [0] => 3
         [1] => 4
         [2] => 5
         [3] => 8
    )
    [2] => page
    [3] => end
)
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/697cb2e6ed6eb67dcaf45fe4cd9a390a50cd5fdd)

**Limitations**

Because PHP array keys are unique, your forced to group all the "split" operations into one lump.  With your current input array structure there is no "real" way around it, even without "using split as a key". (hopefully this illiterates the issues)

```
//The #{n} in the first column, is the (apx) order this thing runs in.
//#(hashtag) will be used for all numbers with a # (in my explanation below)
//if they don't have a # and are code, assume they are the second column value (in my explanation below)

#2    -   0  | from:2  page   | to:1  split //--> start of split
#3    -   1  | from:1  split  | to:3  page //--> go to 3 
#dup  -   2  | from:1  split  | to:4  page // -> go to 4
#4    -   3  | from:1  split  | to:5  page // -> go to 5
#dup  -   4  | from:3  page   | to:0  join //<-- if you go to 0 -> 12 -> end
#5    -   5  | from:4  page   | to:0  join //<-- if you go to 0 -> 12 -> end
#dup  -   6  | from:5  page   | to:0  join //<-- if you go to 0 -> 12 -> end
#6    -   7  | from:8  page   | to:0  join
#7    -   8  | from:0  join   | to:12 page
#dup  -   9  | from:1  split  | to:8  page //--> go to 8 end of split
#8    -   10 | from:12 page   | to:10 end // {exit}
#1    -   11 | from:   start  | to:2  page
```

As you can see above, the `#dup` ones all come from `opp:1` or `$array['operators'] = [1 =>['type' => 'split']]`, but there is only 1 `to:1` at `#2` and 4 `from:1` items.  So we are forced to split the execution of these because you cant go to 4 items at the same time for 1 item.  We can do this with a loop, or with this big huge mess I did there.

For example take `#3` our last good path:

```
#3    -   1  | from:1  split  | to:3  page //--> go to 3 
~4    -   4  | from:3  page   | to:0  join //<-- if you go to 0 -> 12 -> end
~5    -   8  | from:0  join   | to:12 page // way out of wack now.
~6    -   10 | from:12 page   | to:10 end  {premature termination}
```

As you see we cannot follow those paths, so we are forced to process these as a group.  If we did that (follow the path) we would have only processed `#1`, `#2`, `#3`, `~4`, `~5` and `~6` and then the program ends.  This is what happened in my previous answer (basically) and how I knew it wasn't correct. Also due to the duplicated `0` we can't process any of those or well wind up at the end shortly. I don't see any {other} way to solve that given the structure of the data.

**How I did it (briefly)**

The "trick" here was manually mapping out how it runs, above.

1. Using that knowledge I built an instruction list (to reduce complexity), so we are dealing with one array without the lookups for the operation names, I called that list `$instructions` (creative I know).
2. Next `if($instructions[$key]['fromOperator'] == $opp_id)`

   - TRUE: we just eat that `$instruction = array_splice($instructions, $key, 1)[0];` which removes and returns a portion of the array. So our list of instructions is constantly being reduced as we are able to process them.
   - FALSE: we continue to the next instruction and reset the array if the array pointer is at the end. `if(false === next($instructions)) reset($instructions);` and start back at 1 (in this list) on the next instruction.
   - Because there is no "real" way to order this, we may have to loop over the array several time, this is easier to do by removing each instruction as we process it.
3. Then it's pretty trivial to do a switch and collect our output, with a bit of "finagling" with the "split stuff" and the `end` operation.

   - the "finagling" is just pulling an array of all the `toOperator` from the main array where the `fromOperator` has the same int as the `split` has for it's key (or `1` in this case)
4. Lastly we either run out of array items, or we hit this `if($opperation == 'end') break 2;` which breaks out of both the `switch` and the `while` loop.  Who knew you could do that with break {this guy}...

I left a bunch of comments in there, hopeful this explains how I did it and what the main issue was.

**Improvements**

Where I have this monstrosity, which just gets a flat array of all the `toOperator` values for all items that are "Splits" (all dynamic like).  I can come up with at least 5 ways to do this, this was just the way I picked.

```
$output['split']=array_column(array_filter($instructions,function($ins)use($opp_id){return $ins['fromOperator']==$opp_id;}),'toOperator');
```

You could iterate over each "split" and recursively call the switch "somehow".  Because I am removing each instruction, the first "Split" gets pulled out of the instruction list before we can check if it's a split.  This makes it a bit difficult to work with.  However you can do this (if you need to fix that):

```
 $instructions = array_splice($instructions, $key, 0, [instructions]);
```

Which should put it back in the instruction list.  The magic of `array_splice` even if that is a bit counter productive.  Then you just need to loop over them, and if they don't have a `goto 0` you could follow that path where it leads.  Which may solve some issues with ordering, that may or may not happen.  One other issue here is you will get multiple `page` values in the  output, as I just **skip** over them (pun intended).  So keep that in mind if you try to iterate over it.  The way I did it wasn't necessary to deal with that. But the basic idea is to functionality (make part or all of it a function and then)  call it multiple times for the splits as they happen.

One other issue, that I didn't bother fixing, is that not all the `split` items are are actually removed from the instruction list.  In this example this doesn't matter because we have the `end` tag.  However it would be pretty easy to clean that up when doing the above improvements.

In any case I will leave that as an exercise for the reader.

**Final words**

PS: if you numbered it like above, it would have saved me a TON of time.  It was a fun challenge though.

Hope it helps, this is about the best you can get with the data you provided due to the above issues.  There may be some minor performance things to be gained etc, but that pretty much covers it.

Cheers!!

*PPS: yes I know my spelling and grammar suck. Oh the joys of dyslexia. I supose one cannot be good at everything....  It takes me about a billion edits to get it somewhat readable.